# Getting an empty list , while using this code, can you explain why?

Tags: python

I have just begun with python coding. I am trying to read the 2nd column and 3rd column data using the following code :

```
import csv

filename='sitka_weather_07-2014.csv'

#opening file and reading contents of header
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)
#    print(header_row)
    for index, column_head in enumerate(header_row):
        print(index, column_head)
    lows,highs = [],[]
    for each in reader:
        low = int(each[3])
        lows.append(low)

    #highs = []

        high = int(each[2])
        highs.append(high)
    print("lows",lows)
    print("highs",highs)
```

Out put is :

```
lows [50, 55, 53, 52, 50, 55, 55, 53, 53, 53, 54, 55, 55, 55, 55, 52, 51, 51, 54, 52, 52, 55, 55, 54, 53, 53, 55, 53, 51, 54, 50]
highs [56, 62, 58, 56, 59, 58, 57, 54, 55, 56, 56, 56, 56, 58, 58, 56, 55, 56, 57, 55, 60, 59, 58, 57, 55, 55, 58, 56, 56, 57, 58]
```

This is working fine. But initially I was using :

```
filename='sitka_weather_07-2014.csv'

#opening file and reading contents of header
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)
#    print(header_row)
    for index, column_head in enumerate(header_row):
        print(index, column_head)
    lows,highs = [],[]
    for each in reader:
        low = int(each[3])
        lows.append(low)


    for each in reader:

        high = int(each[2])
        highs.append(high)
    print("lows",lows)
    print("highs",highs)
```

And the out put is :

```
lows [50, 55, 53, 52, 50, 55, 55, 53, 53, 53, 54, 55, 55, 55, 55, 52, 51, 51, 54, 52, 52, 55, 55, 54, 53, 53, 55, 53, 51, 54, 50]
highs []
```

So I wanted to know why the second code produces an empty list. Can any one please explain !
Regards
RC

Comment: because you exhausted the `reader` iterator.

Comment: Once you reach the end of the file in the first loop, there's nothing left to read. It doesn't go back to the beginning -- it's not like a list.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `reader = csv.reader(f)` is a generator.
That is, the following code in the second code, makes reader empty.

```
for each in reader:
        low = int(each[3])
        lows.append(low)
```

So,     when the following code was executed, because reader is empty, no iteration is executed.

```
for each in reader:
        high = int(each[2])
        highs.append(high)
```

However, your first code which works fine iterates reader and int value and high value are appended in each iteration.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the clarification.